# link inside a property in Struts2

Tags: jsp, hyperlink, struts2

I'm trying to show a property in my jsp page:

```
<s:property value="News"/>
```

where in news I want to put some text and a link

in the jsp page it shows the mere tag without "compiling it"

I tried

```
This is a news follow the <s:a href="http://www.google.it">link</s:a>
```

and

```
This is a news follow the <a href="http://www.google.it">link</a>
```

How can it be done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```xml
> This is a news follow the <s:a href="http://www.google.it">link</s:a>
> ```

This can't work because you can't nest Struts tags, hence it'll become:

```xml
<s:property value="This is a news follow the <s:a href="http://www.google.it">link</s:a>"/>
```

which is invalid.

The second instead:

> ```xml
> This is a news follow the <a href="http://www.google.it">link</a>
> ```

will result in

```xml
<s:property value="This is a news follow the <a href="http://www.google.it">link</s:a>"/>
```

which is valid, but will be translated in pure text in the JSP.

To obtain the real HTML object, you need to disable the HTML escaping functionality:

```xml
<s:property value="news" escapeHtml="false" />
```